# WPF DataGrid, How to bind property on custom DataGridColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid like this :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgAgent"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.AgentList}"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Agent Name" MaxWidth="140" MinWidth="80" SortDirection="Ascending" Width="100" CanUserReorder="False" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=AgentName}"/>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status"  Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" MinWidth="60"/>
              <DataGridCheckBoxColumn CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" Header="Use" MaxWidth="40" MinWidth="40" Binding="{Binding Path=Used}" />
              <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource sliderTemplate}" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" Width="140" Header="Work Balance (%)"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

It's `ItemSource`property is bound to a `List` of Agent in my DataContext, here is the code of the Agent class :

```
public class Agent
{
    public String AgentName { get;set; }
    public String Status { get; set; }
    public Boolean Used { get; set; }
    public Int16 WorkBalance { get; set; }

    public Agent(String AgentName)
    {
        this.AgentName = AgentName;
        Status = "Online";
        Used = true;
        WorkBalance = 50;
    }
}
```

Each property of this class is bound to a column of my DataGrid. I'm experiencing trouble with the binding of `WorkBalance`property which is bound to a custom column, here is my column template :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="sliderTemplate">
    <Grid>
                <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" 
                        Value="{Binding Path=ItemSource.WorkBalance,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I can't figure out how to bind the `Value`property of my Slider to the `WorkBalance`property of my list. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try replacing the Path expression with Path="ItemSource.(local:Agent.WorkBalance), and set xmlns definition for your local namespace where Agent is declared in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataContext` in the `DataTemplate` is the item, so you can just bind to WorkBalance `directly`:

```
Value="{Binding Path=WorkBalance}"
```